# CSS calc with abs and var does not work in chrome, but firefox and safari

Tags: html, css

I want to change the opacity (or any other property) of the divs based on "id". It works fine in Safari and Firefox, but does not work in Chrome

```css
div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  
  background:orange; 
  
  opacity: calc(1 - abs(var(--id, 1) * 0.25));
}
```

```html
<div style="--id: -1"></div>
<div style="--id: 0"></div>
<div style="--id: 1"></div>
<div style="--id: 2"></div>
```

[image]

Which one of these is the intended behaviour and what are possible ways to fix this?

Comment: `abs` is not yet supported in Chrome - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/abs

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems like I missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily simulate `abs()` with `max()` until better support.

```css
div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  
  background:orange; 
  
  --abs: max(var(--id),-1*var(--id));
  
  opacity: calc(1 - var(--abs) * 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div style="--id: -1"></div>
<div style="--id: 0"></div>
<div style="--id: 1"></div>
<div style="--id: 2"></div>
```